# Sql view based on a flag in column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struck in a very hectic situation in SQL. 
I have a table with the columns (name,is_right) and i want to get a view like:

```
Wrong Name|| Right Name 
Jass      ||  Jasu
```

for the table

```
Name  || is_right
Jass  || 0  
Jasu  || 1
```

I am trying to find a solution for this but nothing works.
Please help me or guide me through any example so that i can pick it up.

Comment: How do you differentiate between different names? 
For example, what happens with the following scenario:
Name || is_right

Jass || 0
Jasu || 1
Peter|| 1
Pete|| 0

How do you know that Jasu and Pete are different names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I will assume you have a memberID for the users.
Please assume @table is your current table with the user information. I assume each memberID only have one value 0 and one value 1**

```
declare @table table
(
  memberID nvarchar(10),
  name nvarchar(10),
  is_right integer
 )

 insert into @table values ('A','Jass',0);
 insert into @table values ('A','Jasu',1);
 insert into @table values ('B','Pata',0);
 insert into @table values ('B','Peter',1);

 select distinct 
 (select B.name from @table B where b.is_right = 0 and B.memberID = A.memberID) as 'wrong name',
 (select C.name from @table C where c.is_right = 1 and C.memberID = A.memberID) as 'right name'
 from @table A
```

---

this what it return

wrong name| right name

Jass      | Jasu

Pata      | Peter

Comment: thanks for this response but can you please give a little idea about the query that you wrote to select it.

Comment: You can ignore the "Declare" and "insert" statement, I just to prepare an environment with your sample database structure.- select distinct to avoid the duplicate data 
- first subquery is to get the "is_right" = 0 but the member ID is same as the main query that is A
- second subquery is to get the "is_right" = 1 but the member ID is same as the main query that is A

In that case, i will be able to get the correct pairing based on the member ID.

Comment: Let me know if you need details explanation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 sub query's. These will need to be linked with an ID to linked them too the main query but you haven't provided that data.

```
SELECT 
(SELECT Name FROM yourtable WHERE is_right = 0) AS Wrong_Name,
(SELECT Name FROM yourtable WHERE is_right = 1) AS RIGHT_NAME
FROM yourtable
```